# Add file name to txt file if it is not zero bytes

Tags: bash

I would like to add files that meet a set of conditions to a txt file for easy transfer later, I do this with:

```
ls -1 > AllFilesPresent.txt

value=$(<AllFilesPresent.txt)

rm AllFilesPresent.txt

for val in $value; do
  case $val in
    (Result*.RData) echo "$val" >> CompletedJobs.txt ;;
  esac
done
```

I've run into the situation where some of the files are corrupted and show up as zero byte files, which i can find manually with:

```
find . -size 0 -maxdepth 1
```

How do I include adjust my loop to reject files that are zero bytes?

Comment: Is `$val` the file name that you want to skip if the file is empty?

Comment: Use that to get the file size: ``size=$(wc -c "$val" | awk '{print $1}')``

Comment: @choroba Currently if $val meets the pattern, it is added to a list for later, I'd like to not add it if can be found by the find command.

Comment: @Nick, I strongly suggest reviewing available answers. The accepted one is not good code -- it'll break badly if you have filenames with spaces, f/e, and needing to create a temporary file to store a directory list in is silly and needless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
ls -1 > AllFilesPresent.txt
value=$(<AllFilesPresent.txt)
rm AllFilesPresent.txt
for val in $value; do
```

has essentially identical functionality to

```
for val in $(ls -1); do
```

That doesn't work in general.  It breaks if filenames have whitespace or glob characters in them, at least.  See [Bash Pitfalls #1 (for f in $(ls *.mp3))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).  In addition, there are particular problems with using the output of `ls` in programs.  It's only suitable for interactive use.  See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

A correct, completely safe, and much shorter and faster, alternative is:

```
for val in *; do
```

A full solution for your question is:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in Result*.RData; do
    [[ -f $file && -s $file ]] && printf '%s\n' "$file"
done >CompletedJobs.txt
```

- `shopt -s nullglob` prevents glob patterns expanding to (what amounts to ) garbage if they don't match any files.
- I've replaced `val` with the more meaningful (to me anyway) `file`.
- The `Result*.RData` causes the loop to only process files that match that pattern.
- I've added a `-f $file` test to avoid processing any non-file things (directories, fifos, ...) that might be lying around.  It still allows symlinks to files through.  You might not want that.  You can add a `! -L $file &&` at the start of the test expression if you want to rule out symlinks.
- I've replaced `echo "$val"` with `printf '%s\n' "$val"` because the original code doesn't work in general. See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).
- I've moved the redirection to `CompletedJobs.txt` outside the loop, as suggested by @CharlesDuffy in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401272/add-file-name-to-txt-file-if-it-is-not-zero-bytes/71403382#comment126209630_71401389).
- Note that this code won't work if any of the files have newlines in their names (e.g. create one with `echo data > $'Result\n1.RData'`).  That's very uncommon, but posssible.  The only way to safely store general unquoted filenames in files is to separate them with ASCII NUL characters (which can't appear in file names).  To do that, replace the `printf ...` with `printf '%s\0' "$file"`.  That would mean that `CompletedJobs.txt` is no longer a text file though.  It would also require modifications to any tools that read the file.

---

You could also do this just with `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'Result*.RData' -not -size 0 -printf '%P\n' >CompletedJobs.txt
```

- The `%P` format with `-printf` removes the leading `./` from outputs so you get `Result2.RData` instead of `./Result2.RData` (which `find` would print by default, or with the `-print` option).
- Replace `\n` with `\0` to make the output safe for any possible filename.

Comment: I have a few questions, as @Rakesh Gupta's answer seems sufficient for an environment where I control all of the present files and folders, though I think I understand the objects to it. 1) I put this loop together because there were too many files present to rsync the `Result*.RData` file set. Is `shopt  -s nullglob` guaranteed to prevent that issue in the lines that follow? 2) how will find work under the similar expectations that i have > 100k files that would match the glob? What about > 1m files?

Comment: @Nick, `shopt -s nullglob` only makes a difference to the case where there are no matches.  Globs can theoretically handle as many matches as it takes to use all available memory, but in practice they would be too slow (due to sorting of the matches) to handle very large numbers of matches.  However, most available filesystems would struggle to handle 100k or more files in a single directory anyway.  If you've got very large numbers of files then the `find` solution is almost certainly a much better option.  It doesn't put huge numbers of paths in memory, and it doesn't  sort its output.

Comment: @Nick, `find` also supports a `-exec` option for running commands on the paths that it finds.  It can run commands on large batches of matches at a time, without the risk of passing too many arguments to commands (such as `rsync`).  That might, or might not, be a reasonable alternative to creating a file containing a list of files.

Comment: the scenario is the consolidation of a large number of files generated from many distributed processes, the current range is > 100k and most likely < 1m files, i decided on the loop because it seemed robust, at the time, for an automated step, if `find` is similarly robust and better fits best practices i assume that's more likely to be best?

Comment: @Nick, in cases where `find` can conveniently be used it is often the best option.  It is generally much less memory-hungry and much faster than Bash loop alternatives.  It is also (if used correctly) generally _much_ more robust than loop-based code that you are likely to find on Stackoverflow, or most other places on the internet.  I think the loop code in my answer is as robust as the `find` command, but I'm less confident in it.

Answer (score -1):

> -s file True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.

```
ls -1 > AllFilesPresent.txt
value=$(<AllFilesPresent.txt)
rm AllFilesPresent.txt
for val in $value; do
  if [[ -s "${val}" ]]; then
    case $val in
      (Result*.RData) echo "$val" >> CompletedJobs.txt ;;
    esac
  fi
done
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you've supplied case with `$val` but test with `${val}` ?

Comment: It is good practice to use {}. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4910/350799. I kept your code as is.

Comment: @RakeshGupta: The linked answer explains why quoting is a good practice, not using braces.

Comment: that's why I am using both. There is no harm in using {}

Comment: Since `[[ ... ]]` is being used the quotes are not needed.  (Confirm with [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).)  Braces are almost never necessary.  `[[ -s $val ]]` would be exactly equivalent in functionality, and some might find it more readable.

Comment: This violates lots of best practices. See [DontReadLinesWithFor](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), [ParsingLs](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), etc.

Comment: Also, `echo ... >> CompletedJobs.txt` opens your output file, writes one line to it, and closes it. It would be far more efficient to put `>CompletedJobs.txt` _after the `done`_ so the file is open for output for the entire loop (and that way you aren't forced to use `>>`, since it's held open the whole time and thus potentially truncated only once when the loop first starts)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy please provide a better answer than just sharing your knowledge in comments. It will be more helpful that way.

Comment: There already _is_ a better answer, written by pjh; no need for me to add another.